# Using the SUM function in XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am currently trying to use sum in my XSLT file, and am encountering some issues with the right XPath syntax to use. Hopefully you guys can help.

```
<all>
    <courses>
    <allcourses>
    <course> 
        <c_code>U65</c_code>
        <c_title>Computer Science</c_title>
        <student>
            <studentID>10265654</studentID>
            <fname>Sarah</fname>
            <lname>Clarke</lname>
            <results>
                    <u_title>Communicating in an IT Environment</u_title>
                    <u_code>CSG1132</u_code>
                    <u_points>15</u_points>
                    <result>65</result>
                    <grade>CR</grade>
            </results>
            <results>
                    <u_title>Programming Principles</u_title>
                    <u_code>CSP1150</u_code>
                    <u_points>15</u_points>
                    <result>45</result>
                    <grade>N</grade>
            </results>
        </student>
        <student>
            *same structure again for each student
        </student>
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to calculate the total number of  for each INDIVIDUAL student? I have tried using the sum function among other XPath syntax to no avail, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and also this is part of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="all/courses/allcourses/course[c_code=$sid]">
    <strong>Course Code: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="c_code" /><hr />
    <strong>Course Name: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="c_title" /><br />
    <xsl:for-each select="student">
        <strong> Student ID: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="studentID" /> <br />
        <strong> First Name: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="fname" /> <br />
        <strong> Last Name: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="lname" /> <br />

        <xsl:for-each select="results">
            <strong> Unit Code: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="u_code" /> <br />
            <strong> Unit Title: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="u_title" /> <br />
            <strong> Unit Result: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="result" /> <br />
            <strong> Unit Grade: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="grade" /> <br />
            <strong> Unit Points </strong> <xsl:value-of select="sum(grade)" /> <br />
            <xsl:variable name="CountPoints" select="sum(/student | //u_points)" />
```

Comment: I guess you want `sum(//u_points)`

Comment: @hek2mgl That will add up all u_points, I want to add it up for each individual student, so for example John smith has 100 u_points and Sally has 200 u_points, sum(//u_points) will return 300, which is not what I'm aiming for.

Comment: In the context of each student (ex: `<xsl:template match="student">` or `<xsl:for-each select="student">` you can get the sum for that student using: `sum(//student[studentID=current()/studentID]//u_points)`

Comment: In your current for-each you can use: `<xsl:value-of select="sum(../results/u_points)" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the **xsl:for-each** that iterates over each **student** (but not within the nested **for-each** on **results**, you can get the sum of all result totals like so...

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(results/u_points)" />
```

The xpath expression here is relative to the current **student** you are positioned on, and will sum up all results within that **student** element.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to avoid for-each. Use apply-templates instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

version="2.0">

```
<xsl:template match="student">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except results"/>
total per student: <xsl:value-of select="sum(results/result)"/>
<!--or sum(results/u_points|results/result) -->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="lname|fname|studentID">
<xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*It is better to avoid for-each.*" No, it's not.

Comment: `for-each` is rarely necessary and not commonly seen in advanced XSLT. The XSLT processor is already traversing the tree; you don't need to do it explicitly.